# PySpark dataframe column name contain invalid characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am working on AWS Glue and i am trying to read a table that is in glue catalog,
like

```
spark.sql(""" Select * from `DB`.table_name")
```

However the dataframe contain column names with whitespaces e.g. `supervisor id`.
No matter what i tried, I cannot even show the dataframe.

Is there any solution to this problem?

I tried the following solutions:

1. to read with explicit rename of columns in the select statement (e.g. `` `supervisor id` as supervisor_id ``), in this case I can see that the column has been renamed when doing `df.columns` but when I am trying to do any operation I am having and error like `AnalysisException: Attribute name "supervisor id" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.`
2. to try `.withColumnRenamed`
3. to try with something like

```py
cols = []
for c in df.columns:
    if ' ' in c:
        c = c.replace(' ', '_')
    cols.append(c)
for old_col, new_col in zip(df.columns, cols):
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(old_col,new_col)
```

Comment: could you show some code please?  "I cannot even show the dataframe" is concerning as spark.sql("select 'a' `a name with spaces`").show() works